# How to create a Unity Editor box grouping with a header and vertically stacked content inside?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to do something like this with Unity Editor for my window but I am not sure how it is done.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6MEy.png

So it is basically a box ( a wrapper ) with a title at top. Beneath the title there are boxes or "cards" where you add text to it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I am not sure how it is done" - Tutorials on the internet, and even many questions here in SO and on the sibling site **[gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)** will provide many explanations and examples for that. --- Other than that, ***did you try anything at all? And if you did, then what did you try?*** --- This site is meant for specific questions; "I'm not sure how to do this" is ***not*** an specific question - There will be billions of ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you're looking to space out and title items in the inspector you can use [Header (headername)] and [Space (space size)] attributes